# Importing FIles on IDLE (python code editor)

Tags: python

This may seem like a stupid question, but I am genuinely having a lot of trouble with this: I need to be able to import a file, like an image, to IDLE so I can open it when the program runs. Am I missing something really obvious or is this not possible on IDLE?
Thanks.
BTW I work on a Chromebook, in Python.

Comment: Hi Viv, welcome to StackOverflow! Just to be sure we understand correctly what you ask. what do you mean by "importing a file"? Because in IDLE you can interactively type in Python commands, load a Python script or edit a text file. If you want to open an image and show it, for example, you have to use libraries (like [Pillow](https://python-pillow.org/)) to do so.

Answer (score 0):

```
from PIL import Image
with Image.open(image_directory) as image:
    pass
```

From there you can use PIL's various functions to edit the image. Don't forget to save it, though.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the trouble I am having is actually importing the image file to call on. I cannot find an import button anywhere, and thus, am having much trouble importing images from my computer.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. With PIL, as long as the file is on your computer (or in a flash drive or whatever), you should be able to access it if you have the correct directory.

Comment: Hmm. I'll try to figure it out. Thanks

Comment: I may be missing something but I cannot import it. I work on a Chromebook, that might have something to do with it. I do have PIL, but I attempted to add the image address and it failed to load.
I know that I'm probably missing something obvious and being stupid, but I would really appreciate help.

Comment: I believe that '\\' is the universal file pathing method (e.g. 'C:\\Users\\Default\\jjj\\derp.jpg'). I know it works on Windows and Mac, but I don't know about Chromebook, and I wasn't able to find anything

Comment: I think I figured it out... I had to rename the file (face palm here). I can't believe I missed that, I deserve to live in the time of the box phone. Thanks for the information.

Comment: Simple mistakes like that are generally the ones that cause problems. Don't worry, it happens to everybody.

Answer (score 0):

You can use open() and read() function.
https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-a-read-text-file-in-python

It is properly shown on the above site.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so other users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).